# snake game in c++: the snake head does not move as expected

Tags: c++

Following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1e5wO7XR2w), I write a simple C++ program with vs2015 community:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
const int width=20;
const int height=20;
int x,y,fruitx,fruity,score; //coordinates for head and fruit
enum eDirection {STOP=0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP,DOWN};
eDir direction;

void setup(){
  gameOver=false;
  dir=STOP;
  //initial position of head
  x=width/2;
  y=height/2;
  fruitx=rand()%width;
  fruity=rand()%height;
  score=0;
}

void draw(){
  system("cls");
  int i,j;
  //print the top wall
  for(i=0;i<width;i++)
    cout << "#";
  cout << endl;
  for(i=0;i<height;i++){
    for(j=0;j<width;j++){
      if (j==0)
        cout << "#"; //print the left wall
      if (i==y && j==x)
        cout << "O"; //print the head
      else if (i==fruity && j==fruitx)
        cout << "F"; //print the fruit
      else cout << " "; //print a space character
      if (j==(width-1)) cout << "#"; //print the right wall
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  //print the bottom wall
  for(i=0;i<width;i++)
    cout << "#";
  cout << endl;
}

void input(){
  if(_kbhit()){
    switch(_getch()){
      case 'a': 
        dir=LEFT;
        break;
      case 'd':
        dir=RIGHT;
        break;
      case 'w':
        dir=UP;
        break;
      case 's':
        dir = DOWN;
        break;
      case 'x':
        gameOver=true;
        break;
    }
  }
}

void logic(){
  switch (dir){
    case LEFT:
      x--;
      break;
    case RIGHT:
      x++;
      break;
    case UP:
      y--;
      break;
    case DOWN:
      y++;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

int main(){
  setup();
  while(!gameOver){
    draw();
    input();
    logic();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This program is expected to behave like this: when I press 'a' **once**, the head ('O') moves left just for one character length. However, it moves quickly to the left until it disappears and then does not respond to my keyborad hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset 'dir' variable to STOP value after one movement in logic(). Otherwise, dir keeps 'LEFT' direction and your snake moves left in every logic() call. Just add following statement at the end of logic() function:

```
dir = STOP;
```